# Weird Java concurrency issue with ThreadPool

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpool, executorservice

I am experiencing some weird concurrency issues that I hope someone can help me with.
This is the code in question: http://pastebin.com/HuDqknNZ

For some reason I have to have

```
executor.execute(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {}
});
```

placed inside the constructor. If not, the program will crash after some time (approx. 20 seconds).
This makes absolutely no sense to me, as the Runnable does nothing, but somehow it affects the executor and prevents crashes.

Comment: Can you post a stack trace or whatever you mean by the crash?

Comment: Also, how is the class being used by other code?

Comment: Oh yea, sorry I forgot to mention that I do not get any exceptions or stack traces - It is like System.exit(0) is triggered. All I get is "BUILD SUCCESS" (as Netbeans usually shows when a program successfully exits)

Comment: What sort of 'weird' concurrency issues are you getting?

Comment: please add (a meaningful subset of) your code to the question.

Comment: @ChuckB http://pastebin.com/6A6ufW8T Here is a simple piece of code that shows how it can be used. (Usually the EventListener would be in a different class).

Comment: @MattImmer Thanks, but unless you show `main()` or some other relevant code, it's not clear to me why you expect your program to run for some amount of time > 20 seconds.  Without that, it's difficult to speculate why it might be terminating sooner than that.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta I will try to put together a piece of code that explains it better. As of now the EventManager is used from many different places in the application and from different threads - That is why I cannot just grab a section of the code that shows it.

Comment: @MattImmer in these cases it's best practice to isolate the issue in a very short snippet that reproduces the problem, so we can figure out where the problem is more easily. This also makes the question/answer more concise and useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

There is no threading required in your `EventManager` class.

I assume, it is used as Listener and hold the `EventExecutors`. When the even fired it is feching the Event Executors and firing that.

If there are no events your MainProgam (other than Event Manager) shutting down the Application (You have not showed What is Main Program and how it using `EventManager` and what is `Event` in your context)

```
private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

executor.execute(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {}
        });
```

The above lines are not doing any activity in your Program. It is just stop the System/JVM getting down. Once you start the executor , you have to call `shutdown()` to shut the `ExecutorService` - Check your `Shutdown` method in `EventManager` class

Thats why without this block your code shutting down ( in your terminology crash) after 20 mins ( after all events executed probably). if you have this in your constructor then you need to call shutDown to bring it down, else it will keep live.

And this is not appropriate way to wait for an `event`

UPDATE:

```
 An unused ExecutorService should be shut down to allow reclamation of its resources
```

from Java [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

Comment: Shouldn't the thread just run through the `run()` method and return to the thread pool, since `run()` terminates immediately? Why would it keep JVM from shutting down?

Comment: @BorisB. That is also my understanding of how things works and that is why it makes me wonder why the empty Runnable keeps the application from crashing. In my mind it should have no effect at all.

Comment: It is an ThreadPool, which is awaiting for the request. You should call Shutdown to terminate explicit . Check ThreadPoolExecutor finalize method . it is calling shutdown explicit. While using ExecutorService you need to call shutdown. try write simple program https://ideone.com/W5jiVi

Comment: @MattImmer , The Work is completed , but the Workers are awaiting for the work.

Comment: @Mani: You're right. The ThreadPoolExecutor keeps the thread alive because it must, otherwise the thread would be collected, which defeats the purpose of the thread pool (Thread would have to be created anew).

Comment: @BorisB. yes , while some of them comment as design flaw .IMHO it is required.

Comment: @Mani Could you please elaborate a bit, because I am not quite sure what you mean. When the FixedThreadPool is instantiated, it is just waiting to do work until it is shutdown. But I cannot see how it explains that if I give it an empty Runnable how it would be different from if I don't give it anything as long as I never call shutdown.

Comment: Because as of now the behavior is that if do not use the executor (i.e. only uses callEvent and not callEventAsynchronized) - the application crashes/terminates after approx. 20 seconds. It runs just fine, if I give that "empty" Runnable. And it seems that it only happens when EventManager is accessed from another thread.

Comment: @MattImmer , It is like hiring 5 employees (5 threads) and putting in bench (pool) . You have pay the cost irrespective of you give them work (runnable) or not. Only way to avoid paying is terminate the employee which is shutdown.

Comment: @MattImmer when you initiates ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5); it will capture the requirement that it should allocate 5 threads but it wont block the threads at this moment. When you give work (runnable ) it will allocate the thread if required . so you have given one work ( which is nothing still considered as work) and java allocate the thread . Now the thread awaiting for work.

Comment: @Mani Right, that is also how I would expect it to work :-) But what I don't get is: if I hire 5 people and don't tell them anything, the whole company shuts down. If I tell one of them to do nothing/wait - the company continues to operate. Because that is what I am experiencing. I'm not calling shutdown on the executor at any point because I do not want to stop the executor. (The EventManager is used as a part of a game so many Events is fired every second, so no reason to shut it down - at least until the game is exited).

Comment: @MattImmer , when the Game completed you should call EventManager.shutdown() to stop that. My first point was you should not use these code at all. remove the lines mentioned in my answer. After that your program might get down after 20 mins. Now think what you want after 20 mins ? you have to show where the code calls exit() . else we cant really answer